# How to set check.gradient = FALSE in lavaan

Tags: r, statistics

When fitting a confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) model using the `R` package `lavaan` I received an error, and it was suggested for me to use `lavOptions(check.gradient = FALSE)`. Though when I do this I get the error below.

```
Error in lavOptions(check.gradient = FALSE) : 
  unused argument (check.gradient = FALSE)
```

Does anyone know how I may do this without receiving an error? I believe my issue is that I am calling `lavOptions()` incorrectly, though I still cannot fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The `check.gradient` option goes to the `cfa()` function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).